# java spring aop: not able to use catch and finally in target class

Tags: java, spring, aop

I 've designed a db application, but need to handle the exception connecting to db using spring aop, classes i 've are shown below

LoginInterface.java

```
LoginInterface(){
   ApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("LoginApp.xml");
   Login login = (Login) context.getBean("Login");
   login.loginMethod(username,password);
 }

Login.java
{
    loginMethod(String username, char[] pwd) throws ClassNOtFoundException, SQLException{
     try{
            ...
     }
    }
 }
```

LoginProfiler.java

```
package dbapp;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;



  @Aspect
public class LoginProfiler {

  @Pointcut("execution(* dbapp.Login.loginMethod(String, char[])throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, java.sql.SQLException)")
   public void loginMethod(){}

   @Around("loginMethod()")
    public void handleException(final ProceedingJoinPoint pJoinPoint )throws Throwable{

       try{

           pJoinPoint.proceed();

      }catch(Exception e) {


         if((e.getCause().toString()).contains("UnknownHostException") ){

              System.out.println("Unknown Host ");

         }else if((e.getCause().toString()).contains("ConnectException")){        
              System.out.println("Connection Problem ");

        }   
     }
   }
```

}

LoginApp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"
        default-destroy-method="destroy"
        default-init-method="afterPropertiesSet"
        default-autowire="byName">



        <!-- Enable the @AspectJ support -->
        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

        <bean id="LoginProfiler" class="dbapp.LoginProfiler" />
        <bean id="Login" class="dbapp.Login" />
</beans>
```

Hi since i need to rethrow the exception in catch to be handled by aspect if i use after throwing advice, i am using around advice instead of after throwing, it is working fine but the problem is, i should not use catch or finally in the target class, can anybody help me to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that: code that calls a method throwing a checked exception must catch the exception, or declare it to be thrown--that's just the way Java is.

AOP functionality doesn't change the requirements of Java itself, although it may alter *runtime* behavior. You may handle the exception in the advice, but that doesn't change the source-level requirements imposed by Java.